# Kendo DropDownList issue calling an action on MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I want to populate a dropdownlist from a action method. when i load the view for the first time it work great, but when I reload the view it doesn't call the action again.

The problem is if I delete an item from the database, the dropdownlist doesn't refresh the results.

My View:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSistema)
                    .Name("ddlSystems")
                    .OptionLabel("<.. Select an item ..>")
                    .DataTextField("DescSys")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "Width:243px;" })
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetAllSystems", "Systems");
                        })
                        .ServerFiltering(true);
                    })
                    .SelectedIndex(0) 
                  )
```

My controller:

```
public JsonResult GetAllSystems([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{ 
    var items = (from row in _SystemService.GetAll()
                 orderby row.DescSys  
                 select new { row.Id, row.DescSys });
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSistema)
                    .Name("ddlSystems")
                    .OptionLabel("<.. Select an item ..>")
                    .DataTextField("DescSys")
                    .DataValueField("Id")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { Style = "Width:243px;" })
                    .DataSource(source =>
                    {
                        source.Read(read =>
                        {
                            read.Action("GetAllSystems", "Systems");
                            read.Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
                        })
                        .ServerFiltering(true);
                    })
                    .SelectedIndex(0) 
                  )
```

******************************************Controller**********************

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAllSystems([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{ 
    var items = (from row in _SystemService.GetAll()
                 orderby row.DescSys  
                 select new { row.Id, row.DescSys });
    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you were to explain the differences between what you are doing here and what the OP posted. Is the only difference the `read.Type(HttpVerbs.Post);` line or is it something else?